# SASS live server updates on main.scss, but not on alternative scss files?

Tags: css, sass

**Update**: I found out I can transfer my CSS into the _base.scss, but the only way to make it update my site is if I go back to the main.scss file, save it, then it updates. I don't know why it only works if I go back to the main.scss file to save, even though all the CSS is in the base.scss file.

I have my CSS working properly on the main.scss file, but when I created new scss files and imported them back to the main.scss file, the CSS stopped working.

[image]

In my main.scss, I removed all CSS and used these imports

```
@import "base";
@import "layout";
@import "components";
```

When I copied my CSS into _base.scss, it no longer worked.

Here is the top of my HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.png" />
```

I tried to reinstall npm and compile:sass, but for some reason, I can't get it to work properly with live server.

Here is the script and devDependencies

```
"scripts": {
    "watch:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w",
    "devserver": "live-server",
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel devserver watch:sass",
    "compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.comp.css",
    "prefix:css": "postcss --use autoprefixer -b 'last 10 versions' css/style.comp.css -o css/style.prefix.css",
    "compress:css": "node-sass css/style.prefix.css css/style.css --output-style compressed",
    "build:css": "npm-run-all compile:sass prefix:css compress:css"
  },
```

```
"devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.4",
    "concat": "^1.0.3",
    "live-server": "^1.2.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.1",
    "postcss-cli": "^4.1.1"
  }
```

Comment: Share your `SCSS` to `CSS` compiler `script`.

Comment: is that my package.json file?

Comment: You can share `devDependencies` and `Dependencies` from `package.json`. No it's not `package.json` file. Like `gulpfile.js`, `script.js`,  `main.js` etc.

Comment: I added the scripts and devDependencies from the package.json file. Let me know if that is what you were referring to